# pine script stop loss not executing correctly

Tags: pine-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5LTf.png)My strategy.exit executes perfectly fine for profit = 50 (ie. exits trade when 50 pips profit are made with resulting £2.5 of profit). However the loss = 25 never executes correctly. I'm expecting exit on loss of £1.25 but the amount is always different and mostly larger than 1.25.
Any hints would be much appreciated

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='Multi-RSI Trend Indicator', shorttitle='Multi- 
RSI', overlay=false)

rsiSource1 = input(title='RSI Source1', defval=ohlc4) 
rsiLength1 = input(title='RSI Length1', defval=4)
rsiValue1 = ta.rsi(rsiSource1, rsiLength1)
plot1 = plot(rsiValue1)

rsiSource2 = input(title='RSI Source2', defval=close)
rsiLength2 = input(title='RSI Length2', defval=10)
rsiValue2 = ta.rsi(rsiSource2, rsiLength2)
plot2 = plot(series=rsiValue2, color=rsiValue2 > 50 ? 
color.green : color.red)

fillCond = false
if (rsiValue1 > rsiValue2)
fillCond := true
fillCond

fill(plot1, plot2, color=fillCond ? color.green : color.gray, 
transp=10)

ma(source, length, type) => ta.sma(source, length)

len = input.int(30, minval=1, title="Length")
src = rsiValue1
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, 
maxval=500)
out = ta.sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)

//maCond = false
//plot(rsiValue1, color=maCond ? color.green : color.gray)

//BackgroundData(symbol, timeframe, data) =>
//  isLive = barstate.isrealtime
//  request.security(symbol, timeframe, data[isLive ? 1 : 0]) 
[isLive ? 0 : 1]
//TimeFrame = input.timeframe("1", title="1 Minute")

CondLong = rsiValue1>out and rsiValue1>50 and rsiValue2>out and 
rsiValue2>50

CondShort = rsiValue1<out and rsiValue1<50 and rsiValue2<out 
and rsiValue2<50

grp_STRAT   = "Strategy settings"
timeInput   = input.time(timestamp("1 Feb 2023 00:00 +0000"), 
title="Start date", group=grp_STRAT)
tpInPips    = input.int(50, title="TP (in pips)", 
group=grp_STRAT)
slInPips    = input.int(25, title="SL (in pips)", 
group=grp_STRAT)

timePeriod  = time >= timeInput
notInTrade  = strategy.position_size <= 0

if  (CondLong and barstate.islast and timePeriod and 
    notInTrade)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry", strategy.long, qty=5)
strategy.exit("My Long Exit", "My Long Entry", loss=slInPips, 
profit=tpInPips)

if  (CondShort and barstate.islast and timePeriod and 
    notInTrade)  
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry", strategy.short, qty=5)
strategy.exit("My Short Exit", "My Short Entry", loss=slInPips, 
profit=tpInPips)
```

Comment: I have tried below adjustments and again take profit works on the dot but stop loss is all over the place . Very strange

Comment: In both cases Take Profit works on the dot but Stop Loss is all over the place. Very strange

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Could you upload an image with the error?

Comment: Hi Gu5stavo71, which script version did you test ... first or second one ?

Comment: I think the first. please edit your post, and leave only one

Comment: I have included the screenshot for the script that is in the post. You can see in the screenshot that take profit is $2.5 as expected with 50pips and 5 entry qty.
Equally I would expect stop loss to be $1.25 , ie 25pips times 5 entry qty. However this is all over the place as you can see